# Door corner hinges pin keeps falling. How can I fix it?

Tags: doors, studs, hinges

Attached is the photo. The pin keeps failing (circled in red).
How can I fix it? Please let me know.

[image]

Comment: That hinge pin is supposed to install from the top, so gravity holds it in. Perhaps your hinge is installed upside down?

Comment: A quick (and dirty) fix would be to *bend* the pin a little, by hitting it with a hammer. This will help it stay in place. Incidentally, this is a common old trick to help keep doors from swinging open or closed by themselves.

Comment: If you're going to flip it over, cut the paint around it with a utility knife or you'll pull chunks of the frame off with it.

Answer (score 3):

The pin should be installed from the top. Gravity will hold it in place. Hinges are typically symmetric, so you could dismount it from the door and flip it over. Alternatively, the plug that's currently at the top can typically be removed. The manufacturing process for the hinges all but guarantees that this plug is fabricated individually and then installed to the hinge with a friction fit. If you have a skinny enough screw driver, then put it through the pin's channel from below and hit it with a hammer to pop the plug free. You can reinstall it in the underside or throw it in the trash.

Comment: I doubt this is the case here, but for posterity I’ll note that some hinge pin caps (the one on top at the moment) are threaded, not friction fit.

Comment: Yeah, that's not something I'd try unless I had it in a vise. Good to know though.